# mysql service can not start automatically at boot up

Tags: mysql, services

For whatever reason my MySQL server crashed (all databases were corrupted) and I had to use `mysql_install_db` initialise mysql data directory. This installation worked. However I have to start the server manually every time it reboots. I have tried to run `sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults` so that it should start automatically at boot time but the MySQL server does not start. One thing I can remember is that after finishing installation using `mysql_install_db` there was this generic message

> "To start mysqld at boot time you have to copy 
>   support-files/mysql.server to the right place for your system"

According to some quarters the right place for the system (**Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.16.0-77-generic x86_64**)) is 
 /etc/init.d/

but the problem at hand is the location of **support-files/mysql.server**. I have tried

> $ sudo find / -name mysql.server

and outputs nothing. Where is support-files/mysql.server located so that I should copy it to **/etc/init.d/**.

MySQL version is mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.50, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64). Initially I used installation DVD to install LAMP. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A thousand ways to kill a rat.The mysql server can be started manually by running the following commands:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo killall -KILL mysql mysqld_safe mysqld
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
sudo service mysql start
```

Automate these series of commands by putting them in Ubuntu ***rc.local file***. A crontab at boot up may execute the commands prematurely.